# Java/Android: When I put a ScrollView - I get a soft keyboard. Can't make a good layout

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have a problem with the layout. I want to place one textedit and one button at the bottom of my activity. And then I want a TextView component that fills all free space on my activity's layout.

I have a big text in the bigText component that's why I need to use the ScrollView.

I have a few questions:

1. I don't understand, why I get a soft keyboard when I place the ScrollView component? But I don't get this keyboard without the scrollview! If I turn off the soft keyboard, like this:

   ```
   getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN );
   ```

   Then how I can use my EditText?
2. Could you help me with my layout? The problem is: when I use the ScrollView - it fills all phone's display I even see my button and EditText which should place below the ScrollView (i don't see completely bottom of my layout). How can I fix this?

And that's my fail attempt of layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bigText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search string: " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Go >>" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've found a solution! I used a RelativeLayout for placing my button at the bottom of the activity. Then I turn off soft keyboard:
`getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN );`
and when I focus my editText - keyboard shows again (now it's normal! :) ) - and I can type anything in this editText. It works! :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN );

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why adding a ScrollView would make the soft keyboard pop up, but it's easily remedied.  Turn it off programmatically like this:

```
  InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)
  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  IBinder binder = view.getApplicationWindowToken();
  if (binder != null) {
  manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binder, 0);
  }
```

where view can be your ScrollView or a TextView or just about anything else

Comment: it doesn't work in both cases :( I replaced "view" with the TextView and then with the ScrollView - the soft keyboard still loading...